# Отправить письмо с кирилицей

Tags: java, email, кириллица

Отправляю письмо с помощью `javax.mail.*`. Конфигурирую содержание с помощью объекта типа `MimeMessage` следующим образом

```
generateMailMessage.setContent(emailBody, "text/html");
```

в котором `emailBody` это объект типа `String` содержащий текст письма с кириллицей в том числе. Но приходит письмо следующего содержания: 
??????? ??????? ????? ???????! text messag (3.0?) ????? ????: BIA-5083 ? R, тоесть все символы кириллицы и некоторые другие (такие как -) заменяются на знаки вопроса.

Беглым поиском нашел решение проблемы с помощью метода

```
generateMailMessage.setText(emailBody, ENCODING);
```

где `String ENCODING = "koi8-r";`, но в таком письме нельзя сконфигурировать html строки, что печалит.

Возможно ли корректно отправить письмо, содержащие html теги (которые будут корректно отображаться) и кириллицу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Ваш проект должен быть utf-8 и запускаться utf-8. Других кодировок не существует.
2. Ваш **generateMailMessage** должен быть **MimeMessage**. Тогда делаем
   `generateMailMessage.setContent(emailBody, "text/html; charset=utf-8");`

Comment: так я ж написал что объект generateMailMessage имеет тип MimeMessage. Но тем не менее, добавив в строку type "text/html; charset=utf-8" все заработало! Спасибо большое